# Array returns NULL in a function return value

Tags: php, arrays, goutte

I am using Goutte for scrapping, I created a function that should return all values, such as URL(a), images(img), text etc. But I noticed that the return value of the function returns null after using `Var_dump` to debug its value. Here is my code:

```
     <?php
      //This is a required file for Goutte framework
        //This file is used for screen scrapping
        //and web crowlling
          require 'vendor/autoload.php';
       use Goutte\Client;
       //===============================================

      //connection to database include file

     include_once('Connections/elecom_connect.php');

        mysqli_select_db($elecom_connect,$database_elecom_connect);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM link_data";
          $query = mysqli_query($elecom_connect,$sql);

      if (!$query){
       echo 'Database error: ' .mysqli_error($elecom_connect);
       }
        //===============================================
       //looping into the rows of url links stored 
       //in the database for fetching and scrapping
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $urls[] =  $row;
        }
           //===============================================

       function getFunctions($node) {
       $client = new Client();
        $guzzleclient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
      'timeout' => 60,
       'verify' => false,
            ]);

         //  Hackery to allow HTTPS
     $client->setClient($guzzleclient);

        $selctors = array();
      $data = array();
     //======================================== 

     //Using Goutte framework to get the client url
      $crawler = $client->request('GET',$node);
     //========================================

     //Filter the DOM by calling an anonymous
     //function on each node (Find all URLs)
      $crawler->filter('section.products a.link')->each(function ($url) {
     //storing the scrapped data in an array
     var_dump($selctors['url'] = $url->attr('href'));

      });
     //=======================================
     //Filter the DOM by calling an anonymous
     //function on each node (Find all Images)
     $crawler->filter('.image-wrapper img')->each(function ($img) {
     //storing the scrapped data in an array
     var_dump($selctors['img'] = $img->attr('src'));


   });
    //======================================
    //Filter the DOM by calling an anonymous
    //function on each node (Find all Brands)
   $crawler->filter('h2.title span.brand')->each(function ($brand) {
  //storing the scrapped data in an array
   var_dump($selctors['brand'] = $brand->text()); 

   //Used for debugging

   });
    //======================================
    //Filter the DOM by calling an anonymous
   //function on each node (Find all Names)
    $crawler->filter('h2.title span.name')->each(function ($name) {
  //storing the scrapped data in an array
   var_dump($selctors['name'] = $name->text());

  });
  //======================================
  //Filter the DOM by calling an anonymous
 //function on each node (Find all Prices)
  $crawler->filter('span.price-box')->each(function ($price) {
//storing the scrapped data in an array
var_dump($selctors['price'] = $price->text());

  });

 $data[] = $selctors;

  return $data;
}

 //End of function

    foreach ($urls as $url){

   $lists[] = getFunctions($url['link']);


 foreach ($lists as $list){
        var_dump($m = $list['img']);
        var_dump($b = $list['brand']);
        var_dump($n = $list['name']);
        var_dump($l = $list['url']);
        var_dump($p = $list['price']);
        $content = file_get_contents($m);
              //Store in the filesystem.
       $save_path = "cachedPages/$rid.$num.jpg";
       file_put_contents($save_path,$content);

     echo 'succes';
    }
}


 ?>
```

After using var_dump to check inside The function it returns the appropriate scrapped data but returns NULL outside the function.

Comment: Write this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($lists, true) . '</pre>';` after `$lists[] = getFunctions($url['link']);`. What do you see?

Comment: @aendeerei here is the result of the output: Array
`(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)`

Comment: Which means nothing is in the array, are my right?

Comment: Right! Put this as first line into `foreach ($urls as $url)`: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($url, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: And? What's the result?

Comment: If you consider using third party library then use https://github.com/rajanrx/php-scrape . As it is configuration based its lot easier to maintain. [Disclaimer: I am author of that library]